# No local degrees of freedom when connection is flat

Tags: gauge-theory, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

I was studying [Chern-Simons theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Simons_theory) and variation of action gives us the flatness conditions $\mathrm{d} A + A \wedge A = 0$. I am wondering how to see that this implies there are no local degrees of freedom.

And what precisely does it mean that a degree of freedom is local?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98484/2451

Comment: Some comments from an alternative point of view on the problem are given [here](http://physicsoverflow.org/23221/no-local-degrees-of-freedom-when-connection-is-flat?show=23269#a23269).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that $\mathrm{d}A + A\wedge A = F = 0$ means that the *field strength* is vanishing, i.e. the gauge field is [*always pure gauge locally*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98484/field-strength-vanishes-iff-a-mu-is-pure-gauge).

*Local degrees of freedom* would mean that the equation of motion ($F = 0$) has *more than one* local solutions that are *not* related by a symmetry of the theory. But the field being pure gauge locally means that it can always be locally transformed to be $A = 0$, so the local solutions are *uniquely* zero, thus implying there are no local degrees of freedom.

Globally, the solutions are given by the finite-dimensional space of flat connections modulo the gauge transformations.

Note that we are talking about 3D Chern-Simons here, the higher dimensional CS theories *do* exhibit local degrees of freedom, see [arXiv/hep-th/9506187](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9506187).