# Pure gauge of non-Abelian interactions

Tags: gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, yang-mills, gauge

if we consider the $U(1)$ potential $A_{\mu}(x)=\partial_{\mu}f(x)$ (i.e. $F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}=0$), then we can perform a $U(1)$ gauge transformation $A_{\mu} \rightarrow A'_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu}f(x)+\partial_{\mu}\theta(x)$, where $\theta(x)=-f(x)$. In that case, we can fix a gauge where this potential vanishes.

However, if we consider a non-Abelian potential $A_{\mu}=A^{a}_{\mu}T^{a}$ of a general non-Abelian group $G$, satisfying $F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}+[A_{\mu},A_{\nu}]=0$, can one always perform a non-Abelian gauge transformation where the potential is equal to $0$ (i.e. $A_{\mu} \rightarrow A'_{\mu}=0$)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Field strength vanishes iff $A_{\mu}$ is pure gauge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98484/)